# Query to return records in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiple select list (links) which posts values to $links.  I then want to run a query on table 'link' returning records that match values in $links.  I am using the following code, but not getting any results:

```
<select name="links[]" size="9" multiple="multiple" id="links">
            <?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from link ORDER BY link_title ASC");
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($query);$i++) {
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['link_pk']; ?>"><?php echo $row['link_title']; ?></option>
            <?php 
}
?>
          </select>
```

And the submit code:

```
$author_pk = $_GET['author_pk'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$topic_introduction = $_POST['topic_introduction'];
$selected_topic = $_POST['selected_topic'];
$links = $_POST['links'];
$majors = $_POST['majors'];
$majors_string = implode(",", $majors);
$sub_discipline = $_POST['sub_discipline'];




 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$query_links = "SELECT * FROM link WHERE link_pk IN ('.implode(',',$links).')";
 $result_links = mysql_query($query_links, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
 while ($row_links = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_links)){
     $topic_links = array();
     $topic_links[$row_links['url']] = $row_links;

     } if($result_links){

$topic = $topic_introduction . '<p>' . $topic_links;

        $query = "INSERT INTO topic (topic_pk,title,topic,majors,sub_discipline_fk,author_fk,created)
          VALUES ('','$title','$topic','$majors_string','$sub_discipline','$author_pk',NOW())";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
        if($result){
            $message = "- The topic '" . $title . "' has been created";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @JohnConde I guess I'm pretty useless around here now that everyone is using that statement.

Comment: You started a movement to make the Interwebs a better place. Be proud. :)

Comment: Yes, I know I need to move on but one step at a time...

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10 times a day.

Comment: @user1911619 Step 1 is move away from `mysql_` functions. They will solve multiple problems with your code.

Answer (score -1):

This line is wrong:

```
while ($row_links = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_links)){
```

... because $query_links is actually a string (your SQL query). You should use $result_links, instead.

Also, the $query_links string isn't being defined correctly. You have to use the same delimiter at the end of a string literal that you use at the beginning. Instead of:

```
$query_links = "SELECT * FROM link WHERE link_pk IN ('.implode(',',$links).')";
```

Try:

```
$query_links = 'SELECT * FROM link WHERE link_pk IN (' . implode(',', $links) . ')';
```

Comment: Thanks for picking that up, but I'm still not getting any results...I have edited the code in my question to reflect the change...

Comment: OP is using this correctly. `$row_links` is the array assigned from `mysql_fetch_assoc($query_links)`

Comment: mmm, in the meantime I have a workaround by just using  <option value="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>"><?php echo $row['link_title']; ?></option> and using $links_string = (implode(",", $links));
$links_body = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(',', '<p>', $links_string));

Comment: njk, that's incorrect. The function mysql_fetch_assoc expects a result  resource, not an SQL string, as its first and only argument. Look at the source above. $query_links is a string, not a result resource. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I've also noticed another, separate, syntax error - I'll update my answer.